# How to resolve this error: skeleton.html:115 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getMood') at getMood?

Tags: blockchain, web3js, decentralized-applications

This is a dapp that I am building. So it takes in the mood and then sets it on the goerli testnet. But I am getting this error => skeleton.html:115 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getMood')
at getMood. Also, it sometimes works and sometimes I get this error. But recently no matter how many times I run the dapp, I am getting this same error.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
    <title>Made with love in India for WEB3</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <B><I><h1 class="heading"> Welcome To The Website</h1></I></B>
      <label for="mood">Input Mood:</label> <br />
       <input type="text" id="mood" >
       <button onclick = "getMood()" >Get Mood</button>
       <button onclick = "setMood()" >Set Mood</button>
    </div>
</body>
<script
  src="https://cdn.ethers.io/lib/ethers-5.2.umd.min.js"
  type="application/javascript"></script>

<script> 

    const MoodContractAddress = "THE_ADDRESS";
    const MoodContractABI = [
      {
          "inputs": [
              {
                  "internalType": "string",
                  "name": "_mood",
                  "type": "string"
              } 
          ],
          "name": "setMood",
          "outputs": [],
          "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
          "type": "function"
      },
      {
          "inputs": [],
          "name": "getMood",
          "outputs": [
              {
                  "internalType": "string",
                  "name": "",
                  "type": "string"
              }
          ],
          "stateMutability": "view",
          "type": "function"
      }
  ]
 
    let MoodContract;
    let signer;
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum, "goerli");
    
    
    
    provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []).then(() => {
    provider.listAccounts().then(function(accounts) {
      signer = provider.getSigner(accounts[0]);
      MoodContract = new ethers.Contract(MoodContractAddress, MoodContractABI, signer);
    });

  });
  
    async function getMood(){
        var getMoodPromise = MoodContract.getMood();
        var mood= await getMoodPromise;
        console.log(mood);
    }
  
    async function setMood(){
        var mood= document.getElementById("mood").value;
        var setMoodPromise = MoodContract.setMood(mood);
        await setMoodPromise;
    } 
    
    </script>

</html>
```

Any guidance will be helpful and appreciated. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: `MoodContract` is obviously not yet initialized at the point in time when you try to execute that promise. You need to do some basic debugging before posting your questions here. I mean, this one didn't even need any debug, it only required you to infer a rather obvious conclusion out of the error message that you've received.

Comment: I am not too good with JavaScript or Solidity at this point of time. Knew c++ and python. So I have no idea what you exactly mean. As far as I understand, I did iniitialize it later at line 64=>       MoodContract = new ethers.Contract(MoodContractAddress, MoodContractABI, signer);  Please correct me if this is not the right way or should I add something to it.

Comment: Have you verified that the line where you initialize it is executed before the line where you use it? Print it right before you use it, and make sure that you don't get `undefined` printed.

Comment: How about writing it this way: 
let  signer = provider.getSigner(accounts[0]);
    let MoodContract = new ethers.Contract(MoodContractAddress, MoodContractABI, signer);
    });